# Controller does not charge, connect, reset, ps button plus share does not work... help

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

blinks orange three times then turns off

when pressing ps button,ps button with share, same thing happens.

when pressing reset button, same thing also happens.

dosent charge

does not connect

my controller wont charge, connect, wont reset... everytime i press the ps button with share or ps button itself, it blinks orange three times and turns off. same if i press reset button... pls help me...

Comment: still does not work

Comment: ps and share doesnt work

Comment: does not show white whatsoever... is the motherboard broken.. or maybe the conductor... i am currently in wired, battery is not connected... when i connect battery, same happens.. pls share this to other people who you think can fix it..

Comment: What are you using to charge it? DS4 is picky about chargers and cables. Try plugging it directly into a PS4 (if you have one), preferably using the cable it came with.